# NEWBIE - Move Data fields in input form

Tags: wordpress, forms

Members, 
as a relative newbie to Civi, i would like move some entry forms for a new contact (in germany, zip comes before city...) basically it is relevant to adresses now, but there could be more fields. I know i could create a custom profile for that, but could you give me a hint where to look for the code? i cannot find the tpl-file....

System: wordpress 4.9.8, civi 5.6.0

i hope my question is understandable ;-).

Thanks very much in advance,

Walter
[image]

Comment: Also noting there are options to make input forms via civicrm Profiles, Drupal Weforms, WP Caldera Forms - all of which make it much easier to reorder fields.

Answer (score 2):

there is a section in the Developer Guide on templates: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/

This includes some pointers on how to customize templates.
Having said so, you might also be tempted to put this in an extension as you might run into some more "Germanization":-) Are you aware of the German CiviCRM mailing list?